# want to know baking time for creme brulee at 225 degrees in the oven

Tags: baking, creme-brulee

im making creme brulee. it says to keep it in oven at 325 degrees for 45minutes but my over is maximum till 225 degrees. kindly advice and for how much longer should i let it stay in oven at 225 degrees???

Comment: Please clarify Celsius vs Fahrenheit. Is that what is off? We welcome questions that puzzle us! :) Welcome to Seasoned Advice.

Comment: Oh yes, that sounds a lot like a Celsius/Fahrenheit mixup! Remember: 325 F is ca. 165 C